# Get the attribute of the nearest line to a polygon

Tags: qgis, expression, proximity

In QGIS, how could I get the attribute of the nearest line to a polygon with an expression (or virtual layer)?

I wish to create a new field in the polygon layer(in this case the parcels) with the names of the streets (the line layer) that are nearest of them. I thought I could use aggregate but I didn't find any nearest function to go with it.

[image]

Comment: can you specify qgis version ?

Comment: Mine is 3.16.4-Hannover

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following expression should work :

```
array_to_string(overlay_nearest('Streets', StreetNameField))
```

Adapt the expression to your data structure.

From QGIS 3.16 on, i think.

Comment: It worked perfectly, thank you very much!!