# Getting values from adjacent polygons or nearest point

Tags: qgis, expression, proximity, point-in-polygon, average

I have joined temperature values from the point layer to intersecting polygons but I have few polygons (yellow in the image) that don't contain any point data.

Can I somehow get average temperature values from adjacent polygons or get temperature value from the nearest data point? Now the temperature values in these polygons have `NULL` values because of lack of data points.

[image]

Comment: for nearest only u can try : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/393016/get-the-attribute-of-the-nearest-line-to-a-polygon for average something more elaborate is required ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use QGIS expressions with the new `overlay_nearest` function, [availble since QGIS 3.16](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog316/index.html#port-reffunctions-to-core) and the `array_mean()` function, [available since QGIS 3.18](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog318/index.html#feature-support-for-min-max-majority-sum-mean-and-median-functions-on-numerical-arrays).

If you already have an attribute in the polygon layer (lets say with fieldname `values`), than applying this epxression on the polygon layer with field calculator will get you the mean value of the neighboring feature's `values` field. The `limit:=10` defines from how many polygons (in the order of the distance to the current feature) you take the values to calculate the mean. You can change this. Setting it to 5 means that only the value of the five nearest polygons is taken into consideration.

```
array_mean (
    overlay_nearest( 
        @layer, 
        values, 
        limit:=10
    )
)
```

**Options:**

If you replace `overlay_nearest` with `overlay_touches`, you only get the polygons that border on (touch) your polygon.

If you replace `@layer` on the third line with `'points'` (the name of your point layer), you can use the same expression to refer to the nearest 10 (or 5 or whatever) points. Further options include defining a maximum distance up to which points should be consideres - just add `,max_distance:= 120` after the `limit` condition.

*Screenshot: the field calculator calculates a value of 18 (see the preview at the bottom), based on the 10 nearest polygons. The lines (created with an expression based on this one) are a visualization helping to understand from which values the mean is calculated: the ten nearest polygons. `array_mean ()` returns the mean value of the `values` attribute of these ten features:*

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I got this to work. I have 10 municipalities (polygons) that have this same problem in about 50 attribute fields. Do you know if it's possible to do this operation for multiple fields simultaneously?

Comment: You can use `menu Processing / Tollbox / Field calculator` and than select batch mode. However, for each field created, a separate putput (file) will be generated... You could than join it back to your original layer. However, there might be better solutions around. Maybe ask this as another question here.